# Another new user chased off

Tags: discussion

RELATED:

[Let's try to work with users before chasing them off](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/lets-try-to-work-with-users-before-chasing-them-off)

This question was deleted by the user in under an hour.

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/122952/im-a-manager-is-my-boss-allowed-to-make-the-staff-do-an-anonymous-job-performa

The comments were reprehensible, including the nagging for him to edit his post and bickering with the user.

By nagging, I mean repeated calls to do a simple edit that anyone could have done.  I was actually in the middle of an edit when the post was deleted.

Comment: Perhaps you could include a screenshot of the post for those of us with less than 10K rep

Comment: @Richard too much for a screenshot, but here's a quote of the OP's comment halfway through

Comment: "Wow I didn't expect to be bullied on my post  It's like being at work . I never said I had a problem with being evaluated by people under me. I would appreciate the feedback . My problem is not being allowed to read the evaluations . That's like being evaluated by your boss but not being allowed to see how they scored you . Considering I have been being bullied and harassed by this person for months.. it seems kind of odd that I'm not allowed to read the actual reviews done on me . So he is allowed to alter the reviews to make me look bad ?"

Comment: @Kilisi What about the other comments? Presenting only the victim's POV can't be judged fairly without knowing the other side of the story...

Comment: @AndrewT. whats the point? If a new user feels bullied, then they feel bullied... the details are unimportant.It's not a court case or an argument. Either they felt welcomed or they didn't.

Comment: Besides, putting screenshots etc. would be against (bypass) the intended 10k rep limit to see certain content and posts (it's there for some reason, so only few users can see to avoid more drama). Not sure if posting it completely would be acceptable @AndrewT.

Comment: @Kilisi well, that's the problem since the welcoming blog post, that anyone can perceived to be bullied and feeling unwelcomed whatever the case.

Comment: @DarkCygnus not really, you can anonymize the users to prevent the drama. For this case, allowing only 10k+ users to know the specific issue doesn't look inclusive enough for me...

Comment: @AndrewT. it's a personal thing I guess, if it was my first time here and people were doubting my question to my face I'd probably just go elsewhere as well. Having said that, I'm probably not particularly welcoming myself, I don't make much/any effort to be PC, but I do take questions at face value in the main unless it's an obvious troll.

Comment: @DarkCygnus it's ok to share screenshots of deleted posts if you feel it's helpful.  The guidance I've seen is that if (some) regular users can see it, it can be shared -- screenshots of deleted posts get posted from time to time.

Comment: People can vote to undelete...

Comment: @enderland That doesn't change the fact that the user felt so frustrated that he deleted it in the first place.

Comment: @RichardU Where are the "repeated calls to do a simple edit"? I see one comment asking for paragraphs, and that's it.

Comment: @DavidK must have gotten deleted before he deleted his post.

Comment: Well if there are lots of deleted comments that only mods can see, then it's really hard for us to judge the situation. IMO the comments that are currently visible aren't really that bad.

Comment: @DavidK Well, the overall point is that we're chasing people off.

Comment: @RichardU And my point is that, for this particular user, we didn't do anything to chase them off. The OP asked a question, and when people rightfully asked for more details and suggested it's possible the OP has some things wrong, the OP then deleted the question and ran away. IMO some of the comments were tough, but none of them came close to being rude. If someone won't even consider that they might be wrong, then there's nothing we can do to help them.

Comment: @DavidK there are no deleted comments on the question.

Comment: @MonicaCellio really?  I coulda swore... my bad

Answer (score 5):

I am confused by the comment:

> @EdHeal You know, you can edit as well, instead of complaining

it is in response to:

> Please can you use paragraphs

Unless there were other deleted comments I don't see how asking for paragraphs is a complaint. I feel that asking a new user to make some simple edits is something that we should do to help a new user. While it is sometimes easy to add paragraphs it is better for the original author to do so, it can help them organize their thoughts.

The comment exchange:

> Please can you tell me that people under you would be able to be
>   honest, if they do not have anamonity?

and

> They will not be including their names ... that's called anamonity.
>   And it's not the reviews I'm worried about . The staff like me and the
>   reviews will be positive for the most part . The problem is my
>   superior falsifying the reviews to his liking . So it's legal to alter
>   documents ?

is a misunderstanding.

the first is asking: if they aren't anonymous would they give an honest evaluation. The second comment defines what it means to be anonymous.

Again unless comments are missing I am not sure how the exchange could have been saved. The question was poorly worded. The question is in a nutshell: I don't trust my boss. I am afraid he will use fake reviews to give be a bad review.